# Best practise for using API_KEYS and CLIENT_SECRETS within settings.py

Tags: python, django, passwords, credentials, django-settings

As the title suggests - I'm looking for best practise for using API_KEYS, CLIENT_SECRETS etc etc within the settings.py of my Django project. I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for on this - documentation wise.

To ask an implicit question: what is the best method for storing this information in both development and in production?

Comment: Specify your question, what specifically do not you get it?
How do you try to do this now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice for using API_KEYS and CLIENT_SECRET keys in `settings.py` would be to not store them there at all!

You will be better off setting environment variables in the OS and retrieving them in the `settings.py` file as and when needed. In this way, your keys will never touch the codebase and remain safely inside the OS.

You can do something like this in your `settings.py`:

```
import os
API_KEY = os.environ.get('API_KEY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE')
CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get('CLIENT_SECRET_KEY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE')
```

Answer (score 0):

I add lines like this to my `settings.py` (This was from Python 2):

```
try:
    from local import *
except ImportError:
    print 'The local settings could not be found.'
```

Then I create a `local.py` file in the same directory that contains settings that are either specific to the deployment or secret. Then I add it to the ignore file for whatever revision control tool I use to make sure it never gets committed.